# Reading querystring param with jQuery returns null

Tags: javascript, jquery, apache-flex, jquery-plugins

I'm trying to read a querystring parameter ("ssip") via jQuery and the query plugin, but it seems to return null instead of the actual value.

Here's is my code:

```
<script src="jquery-1.3.2.min.js" language="javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.query-2.7.1.js" language="javascript"></script>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
  function getStreamingServerIP() {
    return $.query.get('ssip');
  }
</script>
```

I'm calling this method from Flex via ExternalInterface.

Does anyone spot any problems with the above code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same problem.

I believe the query plugin version 2.1.7 is only compatible with jQuery 1.2.x.

On the plugin download page, checkout the API version select box, click apply and you will see there are no releases for jQuery 1.3 or 1.4.

Answer (score 0):

I reproduced this without any problem  my url is :

http://localhost/test/test/Test.html?ssip=foo

getStreamingServerIP() launched from Firebug console return "foo"

Make sure you are making your request against a valid URL and not from a local file loaded in the browser.

Check in Firebug if you have something in > DOM Panel > then in the treeview :

window > location > search

Comment: Thanks. I'll try when I get back to work. I was trying this on a local file and not through http, but I wonder if that really was the problem. In the meantime I solved it by taking a substring of location.search.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I use.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.4.js"></script>
<script>
/**
 * @return null if param not found
 * @return string if param found once
 * @return array if param found more than once or name ends with "[]"
 */
function getQueryStringParam (name) {
    var result = null;
    if (location.search !== "") {
        var querystring = location.search.substring(1).replace(/\+/g, " ");
        var pairs = querystring.split("&");
        var isFound = false;
        for (var i=0; i<pairs.length; i++) {
            var pair = pairs[i].split("=");
            var key = decodeURIComponent(pair[0]);
            if (key === name) {
                var val = (pair.length === 2 ? decodeURIComponent(pair[1]) : key);
                if (!isFound) {
                    isFound = true;
                    result = [val];
                }
                else {
                    result.push(val);
                }
            }
        }
        if (isFound && result.length == 1 && !/\[.*\]$/.test(name)){
            result = result[0];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
/**
 * helper function
 */
function printQueryStringParam (name) {
    var result = "";
    var val = getQueryStringParam(name);
    if (val === null) {
        result = "null";
    }
    else if (jQuery.isArray(val)) {
        result = "[\n\t" + val.join(",\n\t") + "\n]";
    }
    else {
        result = val;
    }
    return result;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="test.html" method="get">
<p>
text <input type="text" name="text" 
value="space: , plus:+, slash:/, backslash:\, amp:&amp;, equals:=, less:<, greater:>"><br>
</p>
<p>
checkbox[]<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="a" checked> a<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox[]" value="b" checked> b<br>
</p>
<p>
<input type="submit">
</p>
</form>

<hr>

<pre>
<script>
document.write("text: "+printQueryStringParam("text"));
document.write("\ncheckbox[]: "+printQueryStringParam("checkbox[]"));
</script>
</pre>

</body>
</html>
```